# local notification are sent at wrong time

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, uilocalnotification

I want to sent 2 local notifications daily at a particular time in iOS,

But notifications are sent at wrong time and also it sends multiple times in day and not once,

Here is my code snippet,

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

 // are you running on iOS8?
    if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)])
    {
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeSound) categories:nil];
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    }
    else // iOS 7 or earlier
    {
        UIRemoteNotificationType myTypes = UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:myTypes];
    }
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;



      //This if will be called only once....
     if ([prefs stringForKey:@"Notification"] == nil) 
     {


 //... 1st notification ...

    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
    [components setHour:11];
    [components setMinute:24];

    // Gives us today's date but at 11am
    NSDate *next11am = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
    if ([next11am timeIntervalSinceNow] < 0) {
        // If today's 9am already occurred, add 24hours to get to tomorrow's
        next11am = [next11am dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24];
    }

    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notification.fireDate = next11am;
    notification.alertBody = @"Notification 1.";
    // Set a repeat interval to daily
    notification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];




//... 2nd Notification ...

    NSDate *now1 = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *calendar1 = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components1 = [calendar1 components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:now1];
    [components1 setHour:18];
    [components1 setMinute:30];

    // Gives us today's date but at 9am
    NSDate *next6pm = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
    if ([next6pm timeIntervalSinceNow] < 0) {
        // If today's 6pm already occurred, add 24hours to get to tomorrow's
        next6pm = [next6pm dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24];
    }

    UILocalNotification *notification1 = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notification1.fireDate = next6pm;
    notification1.alertBody = @"Notification 2.";


    // Set a repeat interval to daily
    notification1.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification1];


}
  }
```

**Where i am doing mistake ? please help**

***Thanks in advance!!***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You check `[prefs stringForKey:@"Notification"]`, but you haven't defined `prefs` so it could be nil, and you never appear to set the value for `Notification` so that could also be missing. Any of these things would mean you're adding when you don't expect to.

You're calling `scheduleLocalNotification:` but nowhere are you calling `cancelLocalNotification:` or `cancelAllLocalNotifications` so, depending on how the user uses the app, or how you're doing your testing, you can easily be adding multiple notifications at the same time. Use `scheduledLocalNotifications` to check what is currently scheduled.

You should probably also be using `currentCalendar` for the calendar as you need to respect the users settings.

Comment: looks to me like the date logic is also wrong. Am I reading it correctly that a date is being created, given a time, a new date is created without a time but the OP is expecting the 2 dates to have the same time?

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin it certainly looks like there's some confusion between the 11 / 6 / 9 times being calculated and set. Looking in more detail, 2 times are created but not actually used, instead both notifications are set at `next9am` which isn't defined...

Comment: See my new EDIT @Wain: I have defined `prefs` in the code i have not added unnecessary code here, above if condition i have wrote there this `//This if will be called only once....` there is one switch when user turned off on there i have written `//Notification turned Off
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;`

Comment: Ok, and what does it do now? Also, note that you shouldn't use `dateByAddingTimeInterval`, you should add a day to the components and generate a new date...

Comment: still the same problem exists, when i log my scheduled notifications it shows many notifications. like `<UIConcreteLocalNotification: 0x7f9e19c77920>{fire date = Thursday, May 7, 2015 at 12:35:47 PM India Standard Time, time zone = Asia/Kolkata (GMT+5:30) offset 19800, repeat interval = NSCalendarUnitDay, repeat count = UILocalNotificationInfiniteRepeatCount, next fire date = Wednesday, May 13, 2015 at 12:35:47 PM India Standard Time, user info = (null)}`

Comment: Remove them all and start testing again